# The same URL, why urlsession gets wrong, but using NSURLConnection always succeeds

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://soufunapp.3g.fang.com/http/sf2014.jsp?messagename=UserCount&wirelesscode=DD146FD49861797918ADA44B7E201180")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url!)) { (data, response, error) in
        print("Always fail")
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(URLRequest(url: url!), queue: OperationQueue.main) { (response, data, error) in
        print("always succeed")
    }
```

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000005ccb0 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://soufunapp.3g.fang.com/http/sf2014.jsp?messagename=UserCount&wirelesscode=DD146FD49861797918ADA44B7E201180,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://soufunapp.3g.fang.com/http/sf2014.jsp?messagename=UserCount&wirelesscode=DD146FD49861797918ADA44B7E201180,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

Similarly, the use of Safari can not open url, but Chrome can get data

Comment: Please check the certificate of https is properly configured or not for the site.

Comment: Set the authorization HTTP header on the request.